# apple sign in : how is calculated the user id?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, apple-sign-in

How is calculated the value of the user id that returns the apple sign in? it looks like `000011.9134c48e58484ad52299cb393541aa78.1781`. Is it a totally random number? Is this number unique per app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple has not provided any information on how the user identifier is calculated. Given that it is guaranteed to be unique across millions of users it can't be purely random. However, there is probably some randomness in its calculation.

Apple [states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_rest_api/authenticating_users_with_sign_in_with_apple)

> The user identifier has the following characteristics:
>
> - Consists of a unique, stable string, and is intended for use as the primary identifier of the user.
> - Uses the same identifier across all of the apps in the development team associated with your Apple Developer account.
> - Differs for the same user across different development teams, and can’t be used to identify a user across development teams.
> - Doesn’t change if the user stops using Sign in with Apple with your app, and later starts using it again.

Comment: Apple's Sign-In will lack sending the users name or email, when it tries to re-sign with your app and there is an Apple Sign-In session still alive. So in essence your App needs the ability to authenticate the user only with the user ID, making you basically store the entry to their account in clear text in your database. This is bad design, good job, Apple.

Comment: The userid isn't sensitive, so it doesn't matter if you store it in clear text in your database. The userid is unique for *that user* on *your apps*, so it is actually quite a good, privacy preserving design.  The user is authenticated by the token that Apple sends you containing that id. You verify that the token was signed by Apple.

Comment: Imagine you would let your users only authenticate using a password. It's unfortunate, because you can't hash the password using bcrypt (which will contain a random salt), and thus you cannot resolve the account to authenticate. Instead you have to use a fixed salt to hash the password. This is what the user ID of Apple forces you to do. A step backwards.

Comment: No, because the userid *isn't the authentication*. It's just a user identifier. The authentication is the JWT supplied by apple that includes the user identifier in the claims. You verify that the JWT is signed by Apple and get the user identifier from the claims. This is a very common OAuth pattern. On iOS this is handled for you by the Sign in with Apple framework.